# What does the “Current Period” data usage number mean?

Tags: ios, cellular-data

In the Settings app, under Cellular > Cellular Data Usage, I see a “Current Period” value of 6.8 GB. However, I’ve checked this number several times over the years, at all different points in my cellular billing cycle, and it *always* hovers around 6 GB. Is this really the amount of data that I’ve transferred using my data plan since my last bill? If not, what does the number mean?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Current Period refers to the period of time since the last reset. This is nothing to do with the cellular plan. You can see the beginning date of the current period by scrolling to the bottom and looking at the date under the reset option.

If you have never reset the counter, it has been counting up like the odometer of a car since you started the OS at a clean restore.

Comment: My period usage was 157 gigs. I about cried until I saw this thread.

Comment: this is a stupid design,  why don't let user setup data cycle?

Comment: Perhaps apple expects that you put calendar reminder for every month start to let you to reset the gauge ? :) stupid indeed.

Comment: @hihell If your carrier supports it, iOS can obtain the data cycle from the carrier and display your current usage for this billing period.